# How can I resolve an 'Out of memory' error in my Hyperlink macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro to take values from column A and add them to the end of a hyperlink, for all sheets in the workbook. I did some digging on the forums and Frankenstein'd the following code, but after a couple months of usage its now giving me a "out of memory" error:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Dim r As Range, s As String, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    Dim rBig As Range
    s = "http://somelink.html?" 
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     Set rBig = Range("A2:A" & N + 1)
      For Each r In rBig
        v = r.Value
        r.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & DQ & s & v & DQ & "," & DQ & v & DQ & ")"
    Next r
   Next
  starting_ws.Activate 
End sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Add a line like `Debug.Print ws.Name, rBig.Address()` and see if any of the ranges are larger than you expect.  Also check you have no worksheet event procedures which might be getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, one of the cells in the range was formatted to be "text" so the macro kept pasting into that cell until limit was reached. I formatted the cells back to "General" and it resolved the issue.

Thank you for your help!